# Easiest way to communicate with HTTP outside of ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, winforms, http, tcp

I have a winform app and i would like to listen to a specific port and be able to visit the app through a browser. I know how to use HttpRequest and HttpResponse in asp.net project. But is there a way to use them in a winform app? or a variant of them? Currently i am using TcpListener and i need to write out my response and parse the request (i only need specific information, it was trivial). Whats the easiest way to communicate with HTTP in a winform app?

Comment: How do you plan to use your winforms app, through your web browser interface?

Comment: If you are thinking of hosting your winforms app inside a browser, ClickOnce is what you might be looking for.

Comment: I am not sure if that will work. I need global hotkeys in my app which will require some C API.

Answer (score 1):

[HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you just have to add the following reference in your references.

```
System.Web
System.Net
```

winform does not add `System.Web` in its references but you can actually add this.  I've done this a lot of times.

Comment: yeah but... with my tcplistener how do i get the request from the client to HttpRequest?

Comment: are you getting the ip address of the http that you will be requesting from tcplistener or you already have the address to create an HttpRequest to? if you are getting the Ip from tcplistener you can use the `IPAddress` of the tcplistener from LocalEndPoint or RemoteEndPoint.

Comment: I still dont understand how i end up with a Http object? The ipaddress is fixed localhost with a user specified port.

Comment: let me clarify, why are you using tcplistener? is this important? what is the url that you want to create an HttpRequest? Is the url that you want to make an HttpRequest come from tcplistener or you already have the url?

Comment: I am using tcplistener so i dont have to use sockets to get incoming connections. What i use isnt important. The url doesnt exist, i am hosting as a server so my browser or other apps can connect through mine with HTTP. I am not making an http request, i (http) response to other apps httprequest to my app.